# Change Background when a different div is hovered

Tags: css, hover

i am totally new in web design, and i am right now struggling with creating part of my website, i need to somehow make this happen:

When PART of the BODY BACKGROUND is HOVERED, make the background change to "B", and when the mouse is not over that part, I need it to change back to background "A".

I have seen some examples here but as i am a beginner, i have no idea how to use javascript, if you could please give me some light here, either on pure CSS or on how to apply javascript.

THIS is what i have so far: ( i tried using javascript) [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rafacardosoc/AGbRH/1/)

```
body {
    background-image:url(http://s5.postimg.org/6qbplw2xj/Background_main.jpg);
    background-position:top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color:black;
    height:800px;
    width:800px;
}
```

and THIS is what i wanted to show up when the COCONUT is HOVERED:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/AGbRH/2/

This works, (Of course the hover div doesn't fit perfectly on the fruit)

```
<li>...</li>
```

In your previous example, you've never closed a "li" tag. Remeber, always close them.

Comment: WHat am i doing wrong @KevinCittadini? it's not working :(
as of right now i have the javascript on the html head, like this:

<html>    
<head>    
<script>
$('#hover').hover(function() {
    $('body').removeClass('nohover').addClass('hover');
}, function(){
    $('body').addClass('nohover').removeClass('hover');
});
 </script>

</head>    


Is that wrong?
here is what i have: http://jsfiddle.net/rafacardosoc/wQdVv/

Comment: In your jsfiddle, to the left, there's a dropdown menu, just under "Framework and Extensions". Choose a "jquery" version to make it work. In you page, instead, put the "hover" function inside a $(document).ready() function. I don't know if this will solve, just do a try.